# Send message to multiple recipients on Java | Javax.mail

Tags: java

My code only sends either the first or the last email, i dont even know why is that.

below is my code

```
// Fetch the emails on the database
List<String> emails = new ArrayList<>();
        try(Connection connection = connect();
            PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT email FROM user")){

            // Get the emails from the database
            ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();


            while (resultSet.next()){
                String email = resultSet.getString("email");
                emails.add(email);
            }

        }catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

// Setting the recipients
for (String email : emails) {
msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.BCC,InternetAddress.parse(email, false));
}
```

I've tried making it an array of string but it still the same

Comment: Instead of `setRecipient()` you want to use `addRecipient()`. The former overwrites all recipients and sets only a single one, the latter preserves the previous ones and adds another one. See the details in the docs of the mentioned methods, here: https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/javax/mail/Message.html

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I fixed it by changing the arguments take by my List as follows:

Just posting here for future reference if someone else gets in the same problem

```
//Fetching the email on the database
List<InternetAddress> emails = new ArrayList<>();
        try(Connection connection = connect();
            PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT email FROM user")){

            // Get the emails from the database
            ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();


            while (resultSet.next()){
                String email = resultSet.getString("email");
                emails.add(new InternetAddress(email, false));
            }

        }catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
   

// Setting the recipients
InternetAddress[] recipients = emails.toArray(new InternetAddress[emails.size()]);
msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.BCC, recipients);
```